# C# Luainterface two dots

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

Is there any way to change the access to my C# object methods in Lua by turning two dots into one? I want to change this:

```
Object:DoSomething();
```

Into this:

```
Object.DoSomething();
```

Without getting any errors. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not without patching Lua.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two lines do different things. `Object:DoSomething()` is syntax sugar for `Object.DoSomething(Object)`. It's what turns a regular object lookup+function call into a method call.

So no, there's no way to do this.

Comment: So, maybe, I can parse my script with regex before running it, replacing ".DoSomething(" with ":DoSomething(Object," ?

Comment: What happens if you have `SomeOtherObject.DoSomething()` where `DoSomething` is a static method (i.e. it doesn't take a self parameter)? That will screw it up. Why are you trying so hard to avoid `:`?

Answer (score 0):

No. Here's an alternative...

You can consider `Object:DoSomething()` to be a .NET extension method. Just like a .NET extension method, you can choose to call it like the "static" method it is:

```
Object.DoSomething(Object);
```